# Disable arrow up/ down when no element presents in its respective direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 10 images in list and 2 arrows icon to scroll up and down to show image (just like a carousel). Now I want to disable arrow up/ down when no more image present in list it's respective direction. Also enable these arrows when next element present.

here is my code.

```
function favscroll(direction){
    var scrolltargetid= 'favorite-link-wrapper';
    var scrolltarget = document.getElementById(scrolltargetid);
    var scrolltargetheight= scrolltarget.scrollHeight;

    if(direction=='down'){
        $("#arrow-navup > a").removeClass('up');
        var targetposition = scrolltarget.scrollTop + scrolltarget.clientHeight;
        var distance=0;
        scrollintervall = setInterval (function () {
            $("#arrow-navdown").unbind("click");

            distance += 3;
            scrolltarget.scrollTop= scrolltarget.scrollTop + distance;
            if (  (scrolltarget.scrollTop >= (targetposition)) || ( scrolltarget.scrollTop >= scrolltarget.scrollHeight-scrolltarget.clientHeight) ){ 
                $("#arrow-navdown").bind("click", function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    favscroll("down");
                    $("#arrow-navdown > a").addClass('down');
                });
                clearInterval (scrollintervall);
            }
        }, 20);
    }
    if(direction=='up'){
        $("#arrow-navdown > a").removeClass('down');
        var targetposition = scrolltarget.scrollTop - scrolltarget.clientHeight;
        var distance=0;
        scrollintervall = setInterval (function () {
            $("#arrow-navup").unbind("click");
            distance += 3;
            scrolltarget.scrollTop= scrolltarget.scrollTop - distance;
            if (  (scrolltarget.scrollTop <= (targetposition)) || ( scrolltarget.scrollTop <= 0) ){
                        $("#arrow-navup").bind("click", function(event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        favscroll("up");
                        $("#arrow-navup > a").addClass('up');
                    });
                clearInterval (scrollintervall);
            }
        }, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post HTML too. A partially working demo/fiddle will be great if got.

Comment: Why `2 upvotes` ? (^-^)

Comment: I don't know if this helps you at all, but I made my version of a carousel with the arrow function: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/ppmutuw8/